# Json data loads only after multiple refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, refresh

i got page on the same domain that sends me the json data 
some thing like this :

```
 [{"clubname":"RC of Madurai West","fullname":"Rtn. AP Athithan"},{"clubname":"RC of Karur Wings","fullname":"Rtn. G Jeyaprakash"}]
```

i call this using ajax and load the data in a div

my html

```
<div id="myags"></div>
```

My javascript

```
   $(document).ready(function(e){
        $.ajax({
        url:"viewag.asp", 
        type:"post",
        dataType: "json",           
        success: function(result){                      
            var data = result;          
            $.each(data, function(){    
                $("#myags").append('<div class="grid-item">'+
                     '<div class="content-box text-center">'+
                     '<h3 class="content-box-title">'+this.fullname+
                     '<br><small>'+ this.clubname + '</small></h3>'+'</div></div>');                
                 });            
            }
        });
    });
```

the names render good on the page, but only after a refresh or multiple refreshes, why not on the first page load?

Comment: are you sure your getting returned the correct data every time you make the call.  Use `console.log(data)` to verify your variable.

Comment: Your ajax call may not be getting the data back every time.  I would try adding an error handler to your ajax request.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try this please:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url:"viewag.asp", 
        type:"post",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(result){
             var myargs = $("#myags");
            $.each(Array.from(result), function(index,obj){
               myargs.append('<div class="grid-item">'+
                    '<div class="content-box text-center">'+
                    '<h3 class="content-box-title">'+obj.fullname+'<br><small>'+ obj.clubname + '</small></h3>'+'</div></div>');  

            });

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why should he try it? A good answer should explain what was wrong in the original code and how the answer solves the problem.

Comment: Why do you need to call `Array.from()`? The JSON result is already an array, there's no need to convert it.